Polynomial remainder with a deformed polynomial
I have a problem that I have been stuck on for several days now, involving polynomial reduction: Suppose $h(x)$ is a rational function:
\begin{equation}
 h(x) = \frac{n(x)}{d(x)}\,,
\end{equation}
and let $b(x)$ be a polynomial. I consider the polynomial reduction of $h(x)$ with respect to $(b(x)-\delta)$, where $\delta$ is a constant parameter, so that we have
\begin{equation}
 r(x,\delta) = h(x) \mod (b(x)-\delta)\,.
\end{equation}
This remainder defines a function $r$ with two inputs. The question is to show that the function $r$ now satisfies:
\begin{equation}
 r(x,b(x)) = h(x)\,.
\end{equation}
for any $h$ and $b$.
Example:
Let
\begin{equation}
 h(x) = \frac{x}{2 x^2-x+1}\,, \qquad b(x) = x^2 - 3x + 5\,.
\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}
 r(x,\delta) = \frac{-5 \delta +2\, \delta\,  x-9 x+25}{4 \delta ^2-31\, \delta +71}\,,
\end{equation}
(where the polynomial inverse of $d(x)$ was used as an intermediate step) and thus
\begin{equation}
 r(x,x^2-3x+5) = \frac{2 \left(x^2-3 x+5\right) x-5 \left(x^2-3 x+5\right)-9 x+25}{4 \left(x^2-3 x+5\right)^2-31 \left(x^2-3 x+5\right)+71} = \frac{x}{2 x^2-x+1} = h(x)\,.
\end{equation}
Partial Solution:
For the special case of $d(x)=1$ and so $h(x)=n(x)$ is a polynomial, I think I have an answer. We can repeatedly take polynomial remainders with respect to $b(x)$ to obtain
\begin{equation}
n(x) = r_0(x)+q_{0}(x)b(x) =r_0(x) +  (q_1(x)b(x) + r_1(x))b(x)  = r_0(x) + r_1(x)b(x) + r_2(x)b(x)^2 + \cdots  + r_m(x)b(x)^m\,.
\end{equation}
This series terminates because the degree of $r_{i+1}$ is one less than that of $r_{i}$, so eventually a constant is reached ($r_m(x) = r_m$). If we take this expression modulo $(b(x) - \delta)$, this is equivalent to the replacement $b(x) \to \delta$ and thus we obtain
\begin{equation}
 r(x,\delta) = n(x)  = r_0(x) + r_1(x)\delta + \cdots + r_m(x)\delta^m\mod (b(x)-\delta)\,.
\end{equation}
If $d(x)\neq 1$ then one can also perform a very similar argument, but the problem is that the series is not guaranteed to terminate. This is because if
\begin{equation}
\frac{n(x)}{d(x)}=\frac{q_n(x)}{q_d(x)}b(x) + r_0(x)\,,
\end{equation}
then in general, $q_d(x)$ has the same degree as $d(x)$, so the "series" is infinite.
The only "intuition" I could think of to tackle the full case is that one can write
\begin{equation}
 h(x) = q(x)(b(x)-\delta) + r(x,\delta)\,,
\end{equation}
and thus if $\delta = b(x)$ the quotient cancels and thus $r(x,b(x))=h(x)$. However, I don't think this is valid because the above identity only holds if $\gcd(d(x),(b(x)-\delta))=1$ and $\gcd(d(x),0)=d(x)$.
I also tried thinking of arguments involving Bézout's identity but didn't get anywhere.
Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like this is a problem that would be best formulated in terms of polynomial rings and ideals, but I unfortunately have no formal training in that regard.
Thank you very much!
Edit: This question is similar to the one found here, for the case b(x) = x. However I would like to show this is true for general (not necessarily linear) polynomials.

How do you define the reduction of $h(x)$ modulo $b(x)-\delta$ ?

It's an instance of the Polynomial Remainder Theorem, i.e.  $,h := r(y)\bmod (y-b) = r(b),,$ i.e.
$$ r(y) \equiv n/d !!!\pmod{y!-!b} ,\Rightarrow, d, r(y) = n + (y!-!b) f(y) ,\overset{y=b}\Rightarrow,  d, r(b) = n,$$ assuming $,y,$ (your $\delta),$ is an indeterminate, i.e. $,r(y),$ is a polynomial in $,y.\  \ $

I should have written $,n(y),d(y),$ above, i.e.
$$\begin{align}
d,r(y)&= \ \ \ n\ \  +\ \  (y-b)f(y)\ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ d\ r(b) = n\[.3em]
d_1(y), r(y) &= n_1(y) + (y-b)f_1(y)\ \Rightarrow\  d_1(b),r(b) = n_1(b)\end{align}\ \Rightarrow\  \frac{n}d = r(b) = \frac{n_1(b)}{d_1(b)}\qquad$$

W.Alpha verification of $\ n,d_1(y)-d,n_1(y) = (\color{#c00}{y-b})(4xy!-!18x!+!5)\equiv 0\pmod{!\color{#c00}{y-b}}\ \ $

@BillDubuque , this is true for the case b(y) = y if I have understood correctly right? Or am I missing something? (I would be interested in b being a generic polynomial)

Above the modulus is $,y-b,$ where $,b=b(x)\in K[x],,$ i.e. $,\delta -b(x),$ in your notation. We are working in $,K[x,y]\cong (K[x])[y],,$ i.e. poly's in $,y,$ whose coefs $,c=c(x),$ are poly's in $,x,,$ as are $,n,d,b,$ above. $\ \ $
